# JavaFX how to Math.round a bind number?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

How do you round a binded number (double) in JavaFX?
I need the number to be rounded to 3 decimal places do the next equation. So I need to change the actual value not the appearance of the value. 
I basically want to do this:

```
 DoubleProperty a= new SimpleDoubleProperty(2.015);
 DoubleProperty b= new SimpleDoubleProperty(9.265);
 DoubleProperty c= new SimpleDoubleProperty();
 c.bind(Math.round(a.divide(b)*1000d)/1000d);
```

I can do the following

```
c.bind(a.divide(b));
```

But that will obviously not round the number.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
c.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> Math.round(1000.0*a.get()/b.get())/1000.0,
    a, b));
```